# Multiple attribute for <input> type="email" does not work

Tags: html, input, attributes

I activate multiple attribute for a `<input type="email">`, eg `<input type="email" multiple>`

However, as I entered two email addresses (like abc@hotmail.com efg@outlook.com) and submitted, an error message displayed saying

> A part following '@' should not contain the symbol '@'*.

I tried the multiple attribute for `<input type="file">` (`<input type="file" multiple>`)  and it was working well. Could anyone help me to explain this? Thanks.

Comment: formatted question to explain problem better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it's detailed in the [MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/email):

> multiple
>
> A Boolean attribute which, if present, indicates that the user can enter a list of multiple e-mail addresses, separated by commas and, optionally, whitespace characters. See Allowing multiple e-mail addresses for details.

In the form, you have to put the different emails separated with comma:
`my@email.com, your@email.com`

Comment: Yes, it works. W3School only uses type="file" to illustrate multiple attribute. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable browser-based email validation altogether, then change your code to...

```
<input type="text">
```

UTF-8 characters can trigger validation on the `type="email"`-HTML type in browsers.  Of course, [RFC6531](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6531) *does allow* UTF-8 in e-mail addresses, popular services like Gmail and Zohomail support UTF-8 addressed email, and in QMail (the massively-popular, Linux email server) also supports it.

`ñ@gmail.com` will trigger this e-mail validation message, even though RFC6531 supports it, so, until that is fixed, just use `type="text"`.