# Multiple attribute for <input> type="email" does not work under ASP.Net-Core

Tags: html, asp.net-core, email-validation

Under ASP we could bound a control with a model which has member

```
   public string Contact { get; set; }
```

or directly `<input type="email" asp-for="item.Contact">` or through corresponding HTML helper

As well we could use Data Annotation instead of implicitly declare *type* in Razor page

```
   [EmailAddress]
   public string Contact { get; set; }
```

But what to do if I would like to enter the list of email addresses separated by comma?

It is correct that unbounded HTML5 code `<input type="email" multiple>` works under latest browsers:
[Multiple attribute for  type="email" does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58726871/multiple-attribute-for-input-type-email-does-not-work). But when I am trying to bound it to the model it looks like *EmailAddressAttribute* is applied to the model and only one email address could be validated

Comment: it's still going to be sent as a single field.  (ex: contact="test@gmail.com, test2@gmail.com".  The browser won't send it separately...) You'll need to customize the validation or use JS to send the request as multiple fields you could bind as a list.

Comment: @pcalkins I would like to receive such list into the property _contact_. It will be saved in database then parsed and handled by another module.
 I could customize the validation and to use pattern through [RegularExpression("...")], but it is preferred to use built-in solution

Comment: I don't remember the being one. You'll have to write one yourself. Could use FluentValidation to make it easier.

Comment: i think this is what you looking for. try to put that under the input ```<span asp-validation-for="`yourViewModelName.Contact"></span>
``` . to change validation messages, you need to put your middleware localization in your project and then set the values in the resources files.

Comment: @JHBonarius May be [FluentValidation](https://fluentvalidation.net/) is nice, but it is not built-in solution.
IMHO, EmailAddressAttribute should have boolean property like _multiple_ to allow to use it like `[EmailAddress(multiple = true)]` with corresponding validation performed by HTML5

Comment: haha, are you still having the illusion that you are living in a perfect world? I hate to bring it to you... You could try opening an issue with Microsoft (GitHub or Developer Portal) but expect 2-3 years before they fix it. Data annotation attributes are pretty old anyhow, and not advised so much by Microsoft anymore.

Comment: Data Annotation Validators are not really supported by microsoft anyhow. Read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/models-data/validation-with-the-data-annotation-validators-cs): _"Although the Data Annotations Model Binder was created by the Microsoft ASP.NET MVC team, Microsoft does not offer official product support for the Data Annotations Model Binder"_

Comment: @JHBonarius, thank you very much for your comments. My aim was to understand which tool could be used for what is requested in the best way. Using _Regular Expression_ annotation is good enough, but I would like to be sure that `DataType.EmailAddress` approach does not fit with my requirement. P.S. I am mature enough to resolve specific problems assigned to me and do not spend time for tilting at windmills BTW, from your profile maybe we were colleagues in the past - in 2011, 2012 I have been worked for Philips in Brugge

Comment: @pcalkins you make a good point, he needs to implement the custom validator, I quickly coded out a sample ... may have a few compile errors.. but he can see the flow.

Answer (score 1):

Like @pcalkins said, the browsers will not separate it for you, you have to implement some split emails functionality like so

```csharp
// 1. put this helper in your utilty class
private IEnumerable<string> GetEmails(string input)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(input)) yield break;
    MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(input, @"[^\s<]+@[^\s,>]+");
    foreach (Match match in matches) yield return match.Value;
}
```

---

```csharp
// 2. now call it to get list of emails
// for e.g. string strEmails = "Last, First <name@domain.com>, name@domain.com, First Last <name@domain.com>..";
string allContactsWithCommas = model.contactsWithCommas;
IEnumerable<string> emails = GetEmails(allContactsWithCommas );
```

---

```csharp
// 3. try to give it something custom to validate
//[Required, MinLength(1, ErrorMessage = "Some validation error")]
[YourClassHoldingObject]
public List<int> Contact { get; set; }
```

---

```csharp
// 4. or implement something custom in for your validation object, so the broswer knows how to handle/waht to call for validation
public class YourClassHoldingObject : IValidatableObject
{
    [Required]
    List<int> Contact 

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
    // your contact logic validation here
        if (Contact.Count < 1)
        {

            // some validation using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations
            // - please customize for your needs
            yield return new ValidationResult(
                $"At least one email should be specified.", new[] 
                { System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.EmailAddressAttribute().IsValid(
                // for e.g. "email@istart.work") });
                Contact) });
        }
    }   
}
```

---